# Why does Webpack with Vue.js produce such a large build file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, vue.js

I've cloned this repository:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Vue-Starter

I run npm scripts:

```
npm install
npm run build
```

The result: build.js filzesize is about 1MB.

For a simple example, why is build.js so much bigger than the Vue.js library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that Webpack 2 is installed in package.json.
You will have to optimize the bundle yourself through the webpack.config.js and manage environment variables to reduce the bundle size.

Alternatively, you can install Webpack 4 instead and change the build script to:

```
"build": "webpack --mode production"
```

Webpack will take care of optimizing the bundle with sensible defaults.

[Reference](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/)